# Vector layer being drawn before the Openlayers map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

this is my code for the drawing

```
 const drawLines = () => {

    const points = [[-89.8802, 32.5804], [44.419834, -97.568073]];

    const featureLine = new Feature({
      geometry: new LineString(points),
    });

    const vectorLine = new VectorSource({});
    vectorLine.addFeature(featureLine);

    const vectorLineLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: vectorLine,
      style: new Style({
        fill: new Fill({ color: 'red', weight: 10 }),
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 10 }),
      }),
    });
    mapReference.addLayer(vectorLineLayer);

  };
```

however I see that my drawing happens before my map is actually displayed and my map sits on top of it.
[breakpoint for when drawing is done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXxoq.png)

How can I make sure that my drawing is done after my map is displayed?

Comment: Before you call `.addLayer()` do `vectorLineLayer.setZIndex(<some higher number or calc'd based on layer count goes here>);`

Comment: Or wait for the map with its base layer to render before calling `drawLines`  e.g. `mapReference.once('rendercomplete', drawLines);`

Comment: @ChrisW. your suggestion didn't work for some reason, had to manually set the zindex through css

Comment: @Mike didn't work either, had to manually set zindex through CSS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer